# Is it posible to create a custom burndown chart in visualstudio.com

Tags: scrum, azure-devops, burndowncharts

I am very new to using SCRUM in VisualStudio.com and **I need to create a Burndown Chart of only certain Tasks. (for example a burndown of only the Developmente tasks or only the tasks that assigned to Developer A and B)**

To try to achieve this I created a `Query` that produces a `Flat List of Work Items` and tried to creat a `Chart` based on that `Query`, but none of the type of chars seem to match what I need,

This are the type of charts that are available to be created `Pie, Bar, Column, Stacked Bar` and `Pivot Table` and try all of them but did not find anything that resemebles a `Burndown Chart`

Can please someone **let me know if this can be done and point me out how to achieve it.**

Comment: mora than a 1K views and not a single upvote ?? :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is my understanding that the burndown chart is specific to the current sprint, and doesn't apply anywhere else in Scrum. If you are trying to have separate charts for separate teams (or projects), then you are encouraged to create a new team (or a new project) and manage the two separately.

**One way to achive this is to (re)structure al the development task in a single project and the rest as a Miscellaneous project then you can see the burndownchart of each project**

Comment: Pavlindrom what I want to do is have burdownchart for Development tasks and another burdownchart for other kind of tasks. So this does not answer my question unless you are suggesting that I create a new team just for developers and another for any other type of team members

Comment: There is no straightforward way to do that, unless you restructure the development as a project, and the rest as a Miscellaneous project. I haven't found anything resembling a note about VSOnline extensions.

Comment: pavlindrom thanks for the feeback. Do you know if Kanbanize.com or Trello.com handle this kind of burndown charts that I am looking for ?

Comment: I am not familiar with these tools. After some searching, Trello seems to not give you anything like a sprint, which is a must for a burndown chart to me; Kanbanize may get (or has it already, no new updates) something like it:  [Google Groups Post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/com_kanbanize/YFoNofFjXRY/3eYGyww8pmYJ)

Comment: You can have Burn Down chart per Team. We have created Different teams like DEV, BA & PM each having their own burndown chart. To create totally custom burn down chart you will have to do it via SSRS, Excel or Power BI